# What is the best way to obtain a "vertical" subset symbol?

Tags: symbols, rotating

I am trying to typeset a table indicating various kinds of `$\subset$` relations for objects in a grid.  Is there a way to obtain a subset symbol that applies vertically, between objects where one is above the other?  Detexify doesn't seem to have a symbol like this, although there are many vertical arrow-like objects in the Comprehensive LaTeX Symbol List.

This can be done by drawing a picture (e.g. with TiKZ or Xy-pic), or one could apply a rotation somehow to a standard "horizontal" symbol.  I would be happy with a solution that only worked with PDF files.

Is there a "best practice" for rotating individual symbols?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `graphics` package also lets you rotate boxes, as explained in Section 7.2 of Lamport's *LaTeX: A document preparation system*. You use `\rotatebox{x}{text}`, where `x` is a specified angle in the positive (counterclockwise) direction with the "positive *x*-axis", which extends horizontally from the basepoint of the box that contains `text`.

Answer (score 4):

A quick way: you could use `\cap` and `\cup`.

For rotating I would use `\rotatebox` of the `graphicx` package.

Comment: Unfortunately I need subset-like symbols, like `\sqsubseteq` and `\subsetneq`.  I'll take a look at \rotatebox.